# In App Purchase: Can not track process CANCEL or SUCCESS

Tags: ios, transactions, swift2, in-app-purchase

When I use IAP to test in sandBox, I have 2 case:

- Case 1: If I buy item successfully. `transaction.state` switch to `Purchased` key.
- Case 2: If I cancel when Iphone asking me to login Apple ID or accept the payment. `transaction.state` switch to `Purchased` key too.

How to solve my problem? how to know user cancel or not?
Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
When I test in simulator, the `SKPaymentTransactionState` switch to `Failed` when I cancel In App Purchase request Apple ID.

But, when I test in real device, the `SKPaymentTransactionState` swtich to `Purchased` when I cancel In App Purchase request Apple ID. The `transaction.error` always `nil`.

I don't know why.

**UPDATE:**

- I can't track TransactionState because I have used my boss device which has been jailbreak and use Local validate Receipt . OMG.
- Thank you for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
            NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

For more,

```
switch (transaction.error.code) {
    case SKErrorUnknown:
        //Unknown error
        break;
    case SKErrorClientInvalid:
        // client is not allowed to issue the request, etc.
        break;
    case SKErrorPaymentCancelled:
        // user cancelled the request, etc.
        break;
    case SKErrorPaymentInvalid:
        // purchase identifier was invalid, etc.
        break;
    case SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed:
        // this device is not allowed to make the payment
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about my lately response. Because i don't have device to test.
I try your method but. the `transaction.error.code` always `nil`